# How can I /give a player a named arrow in Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to give a player a specified item that makes something when used, but first I need to actually give them the item, and that's where I'm stuck. I am attempting to use the following command:

```
/give @p arrow 1 1 {display:{Name:"Arrow of destiny"}}
```

However I'm getting the error:

> Line 1, Column 2
> Missing '}' or object member name

Why is this not working? What am I doing wrong?

[image: Command block window]

Answer (score 5):

Pocket edition does not allow NBT access with commands, so you cannot use commands to give named items in pocket edition.

Instead, you could rename the items in advance (with an anvil or external editor), then put them in a dispenser (or even teleport the item to the player when it's needed).

Comment: How can you teleport an item to a player?